# Building webapp for rendering (>20,000) zoomable and interactive objects

Tags: web-applications, rendering, webgl, pixi.js, deck.gl

I am trying to build a web-based user interface, which consists of over 20,0000 objects to render. The application is very similar to geospatial rendering but with 2D objects instead of geo JSON. The objects are arranged hierarchically and expected to display information on mouse-hover with dynamic pan/zoom ability.

I built the initial prototype with SVG but quickly realized its scalability issue and started working with Paper.js and PIXI.js (Canvas and WebGL engines). I am able to render fairly complex images now but the mouse events for such a large number of objects are getting very difficult to track.
recently I came across [deck.gl](https://deck.gl) which actually displays mouse hover events, but it does not change anything in the scene based on the hover or click event (I am guessing the library maintains the pixel to object mapping in the background, but frequent scene redraw is costly).

In the future, the application will require more interactivity like:

- Zoom on rectangle
- Selection on rectangle
- Drag and delete objects

I am wondering what could be the best technology to use for this application to ensure interativity and better scalability.

[image: https://www.techdesignforums.com/practice/files/2019/06/Layouts_clips_Fig1.jpg]
https://www.techdesignforums.com/practice/files/2019/06/Layouts_clips_Fig1.jpg

Comment: It's a broad question but some thoughts: if it's ok to lose some detail when zooming out, you could look into tiling the data and storing it in a vector tiles format. Deck GL has good support for tiled layer e.g. `MVTLayer`.

Comment: Also, deck.gl does have a built-in feature to change the hovered feature color (through the `autoHighlight` and `highlightColor` properties of layers). It's enough for basic needs, and you can easily implement more complex interactions yourself. The hover/click (picking in deckgl terms) works by rendering visible layers to an offscreen buffer with a unique color assigned to each layer. The colour of the pixel under the cursor identifies the interacted layer.

Comment: Finally, it's not really true to say that frequent scene redraw is costly, as deck.gl essentially does redraw the scene on every frame. If anything, changing the data (or changing the attribute accessors such as `getColor` often) is expensive because it requires recalculating the rendered attributes of each feature. But it seems that your data doesn't change, it's rather that the user zooms/pans a lot. This should work well in deck.gl, but perhaps you want to think about tiling to reduce the data loading needs?